# Quickly doesn't push - Intended?

Tags: application-development, quickly

I have setup Quickly with my launchpad Project

```
quickly configure bzr lp:~me/projectname/trunk
```

But when I do `save`, `share` or `release`, no code is pushed to the repository. Is this supposed to happen? If not, what would be the correct workflow; 1) `bzr push` then 2) `quickly share`? Because the latter affects the files. Or should it be the other way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `quickly save` command will only save (commit) your work locally.

Remember you can use `quickly help <commandname>` to learn more about commands. In th current case:

```
$ quickly help save
Usage: quickly save [comments]

This command commits all changes since the last save to bzr. Note that 
it does not push changes to any backup location. If you need revert
or otherwise use the revision control, use bzr directly:
$ bzr help
```

In order to push it to the remote project in Launchpad, you can use `bzr` directly:

- `bzr push lp:projectname` the first time (you might have to use the `--remember` option)
- And on subsequent pushes you can use `bzr push` or `bzr push :parent`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
quickly configure ppa projectname
```